# Как задавать программно текущее положение ScrollBar'а

Tags: unity3d, ui

Ситуация следующая. В Unity3d 5, используя встроенные UI-компоненты, создал с помощью `scrollRect` и `scrollBar` область с генерируемым контентом внутри.

В коде сначала смотрю кол-во элементов, которые нужно сгенерировать-отобразить, затем увеличиваю `Rect.size.y` на `ElementsCount * индекс высоты одного элемента`. `ScrollBar` автоматический, вертикальный. Размеры делает нормально, но постоянно при перестройке содержимого `ScrollBar` выставляется по центру контента, а нужно отображать сверху контента.

По советам на просторах - менял привязку в UI, но почему-то изменений не заметил. Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с этой проблемой и подскажет примерное решение. Пока из мыслей костыль написать - высчитывать нужные координаты для самого `scrollRect` и двигать его, а на `ScrollBar` пока забить, но выход, по мне, не лучший.

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Приложите картинку что не так, а то с описания не совсем понятно. Я так понял, что вы обновляете список объектов и у вас область выставляет на середину списка. Если у вас `scrollBar` напрямую влияет на положение области, и вы хотите после каждого обновления списка объектов в `scrollRect` то просто сбрасывайте scrollBar.value в 0.

Comment: С аналогичной проблемой встретился на другом ресурсе: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/857051/ui-46-scrollbarvalue-sets-to-1-first-time-but-not.html#answer-857482 Скомбинировал ваш совет с советом на ресурсе и похоже заработало. Наверное, оформлю в ответ, что сделал в итоге.

Comment: Установил Direction = BottomToTop, а Pivot по совету с ресурса установил = 1. И программно задавал _myScroll.Value = 1 после того, как менял в скрипте размеры поля скроллируемого. До этого пробовал отдельно некоторые варианты и это не давало эффекта. А сейчас все стало хорошо. Спасибо за помощь. Иногда не хватает чуть-чуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена следующим образом:
в настройках `ScrollBar` установил `Direction = BottomToTop`, там где в компоненте был установлен `Pivot` (по Y) равным 0,5 - установил равным 1.
В скрипте, сразу после изменения размера `scrollRect` - устанавливал `<Мой_скроллбар>.Value = 1;`